# KeyError in main while making project using django

Tags: python, django

This is my code:

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City

def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=bd5e378503939ddaee76f12ad7a97608'
    city = 'Jaipur'
    cities = City.objects.all()
    weather_data = []

    for city in cities:
        r = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()
        city_weather = {
            'city' : city.name,
            'temperature' : r['main']['temp'],
            'description' : r['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon' : r['weather'][0]['icon'],
        }
    weather_data.append(city_weather)

    context = {'weather_data': city_weather}
    return render(request, 'weather/weather.html', context)
```

I'm getting the error like this:

```
KeyError at /
'main'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0.6
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'main'
Exception Location: C:\Users\HP\p\the_waether\weather\views.py in index, line 18
Python Executable:  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: are you shure you have all keys in your json in the rquest?

Comment: `r['main']` I think, you don't have this key, if I make a request with the url you provided the response doesn't have `main` key.

Comment: so, what i  have to do now?

Comment: Actually, there must be some cities name in your City object which is unavailable in the api. Thus it gives you the 404 city not found response, and in that case the `main` would be undefined. While I put "Jaipur" as city, the code works fine.

Comment: You are getting error on this line, `'temperature' : r['main']['temp'],` I hope you'll debug the line and fix it

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your code. I had the same problem and the issue was when you enter a city that does not exist in 'openweatherapp' database, it gave you an error because it could not find the weather data for it. What you need to do is add a try and except statement to catch the error.

Don't forget to enter your app id.

Code :-

```
def index(request):
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=c12a48c9ac1ec37bedd3cc51b1af4e8b'
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CityForm(request.POST)
    form.save()

form = CityForm()

cities = City.objects.all()
weather_data = []
try:
    for city in cities:
        r = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

        city_weather = {
        'city' : city.name,
        'temperature' : r['main']['temp'],
        'description' : r['weather'][0]['description'],
        'icon' : r['weather'][0]['icon'],
        }

        weather_data.append(city_weather)
except KeyError:
    pass
except EXCEPTION as e:
    pass

context = {'weather_data' : weather_data, 'form' : form}
return render(request, 'weather/weather.html', context)
```

Comment: EDIT :- 
you might also want to delete the record that caused the error with the except part to make the app run again as normal as it was

Answer (score 0):

There must be in error in your models.py file

Change this,

`def _str_(self):
    #some code`

To,

`def __str__(self):
    #some code`

Comment: You must know what you are saying

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I faced the same error from that code [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-weather-app-in-django) this is its source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this error. The error is that my API key is wrong.

So, You go [for API key link](https://openweathermap.org) and register then  [select free plan](https://openweathermap.org/price) and click on get API and check your email. insert the API key in the URL.

`url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=YOUR_API_KEY'`

thats all

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make changes in your code by simply removing some code in this section:

```
for city in cities:
    city_weather = {
        'city' : city.name,
        'temperature' : temp,
        'description' : description,
        'icon' : icon,
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error because you have entered some random words in the 'Add City' box instead of city names. Go to the admin panel, go to cities and delete random words other than the city names. (Admin>Weather>Cities)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in cities in the admin dashboard after creater a super user by running `python manage.py createsuperuser` and add a city then refresh the url. the reason as to why the key error persists is that there is no matching record of cities in the db